# Discrepancy between review alert and actual queue

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-queue

Anyone else notice the difference in the queue count icon and the actual review queue. I find it quite annoying....

Here it shows 8 items, but the actual queue is empty. The variance also varies and is never the same or easy to identify a cause.

[image: Queue notification]

[image: Actual Queue]

Comment: The review queue count is [heavily cached](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251914/164200) which results in the number not always appearing to be accurate causing the discrepancy. [This has been discussed on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238515/164200).

Comment: Thanks for the post. Should I delete this, or can you post that as an answer?

Comment: I don't think it's the only reason though. See also http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2173/posts-awaiting-review-broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, the number shown in the review queue is [heavily cached](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251914/164200) because it's a monster query to get those numbers so real-time updates don't show.

The caching on those numbers is about [5 minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237873/164200) to help with hitting the database too often. This isn't a bug it's [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).